# How to explain this string of downvotes?

Tags: discussion, support, down-votes, closed-questions

This is the first time I met such phenomenon. At the same time two old questions

[Is there a $2 \times 2$ real matrix $A$ such that $A^2=-4I$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2448604/is-there-a-2-times-2-real-matrix-a-such-that-a2-4i)

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2429346/multiplication-of-two-matrices-and-null-spacewith [now deleted]

with many old answers to these questions were "put on hold" and additionally extensively downvoted. Moreover **all** the answers were downvoted.

Could someone explain what's going on here? Is it some kind of vandalism or something else? Can it be reversed?

Comment: Probably it would be ideal to get some response from the users who actually voted to close and/or downvoted. In any case, maybe these posts and some other discussions linked there might be of interest: [Downvotes on answers to 'poor' questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/26611) and [Is it acceptable to answer a poor quality question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27259)

Comment: @MartinSleziak   This is a mysterious affair, the old questions are taken to be serially downvoted at the same time questions and answers. Some purpose  is here, it is evident. Probably the responsible is the first person initiating the action.. sometimes I wonder whether some users do not have a multiple accounts to amplify their actions whatever they are... I don't know whether a try to get directly some response is a good idea in the case where someone is acting on purpose..

Comment: This doesn't look like serial downvoting. You've only received a total of three down votes on two questions. Now, the fact that *two* voters voted down answers from a few months ago suggests that the voting was *coordinated*, almost certainly by the folks in the [CRUDE chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/crude).

Comment: @MarkMcClure I'm not talking only on myslelf, all answers were downvoted.  Voting was coordinated, it is evident. What was the purpose of that, it's hard to guess, interesting that some who put the questions of hold don't restraint themselves for answering sometimes the very simple questions.. I do not understand the motivation..

Comment: There could be one person downvoting all answers.

Comment: @Widawensen Yes, the voting was coordinated. I thought I said that. :) In fact, the questions you refer to were singled out [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42897433#42897433). If you read in that chatroom a bit, it's clear that the folks there believe that problems stated straight from textbooks should be purged from the site and folks should be discouraged from answering such questions in the first place. Hence, your downvotes. To answer your question to John Ma, though - no, there is (by design) no reliable way to find out who specifically downvoted your answer.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I could understand that **new** questions  be discouraged, but old ones with many answers ? This is a total disregard for the work of others, I've read some discussion in this room. I didn't expect such great portion of cynicism here..

Comment: Flag one of the downvoted answers for moderator attention, and explain the situation to the moderator. If there has been some violation of rules, only the moderators can do anything about it. (But how do you know that answers other than your own have been downvoted at the same time as yours? Do you keep track of all the scores of all the answers on all the questions you answer?)

Comment: @GerryMyerson  I'm afraid to do that... "But how do you know that answers other than your own have been downvoted at the same time as yours?" - I've simply checked other users reputation, they received exactly -2 at the same time, records of downvoting are available to anyone.. such coordinated actions should be prohibited, a single person always will lose with the "organization"..

Comment: I don't understand – you're not afraid to raise the issue in a post here, that everyone can see, but you are afraid to notify the moderators?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, I'm afraid now after visiting this awful crude room.. I was more optimist one hour ago..

Comment: Sorry, now there is hint that one person voted on all the answers. That is not against the rule. Indeed I find it quite common: I just spent 3 upvotes today on one thread. Several days ago I spent 6 votes (3 up 3 down) on one thread.

Comment: @Widawensen You should not be afraid of the moderators. They are generally quite nice and one of them would quite likely give a reasonable response to a flag on this issue. You do need to know to look for a response on [your flag-summary page](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/flag-summary/334463). Having said that, I seriously doubt that any specific rules have been broken and I think that one can make a reasonable argument against PSQs, as they call them. I'm not sure where I stand on the issue myself.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I've checked the record of answers of some people who so easily are tracking   supposed  old PSQ , they don't hesitate to answer sometimes the obvious questions... why in that case   disregard so much  others work? Simply , I don't understand..

Comment: @Widawensen I cannot speak for others. I'm simply letting you know why your answers to PSQs might be downvoted.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Yes, thank you for the explanation, I see now more than 1 hour ago..

Comment: Perhaps related: math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15126/is-it-appropriate-to-downvote-answers-for-the-sake-of-deleting-a-question

Comment: "Serial downvoting" refers to downvoting many questions or answers by the same user only because of the identity of the user, without regard to other factors. It often arises as a "tit for tat" phenomenon - "if I think you downvoted me, I will downvote you!" .  Downvoting several posts by different users is not serial downvoting, and even downvoting several posts by one user may not be serial downvoting if the quality of the posts, rather than the identity of the users, is what motivated the voting.

Comment: @CarlMummert I used the name "serial" for downvoting en masse all answers in the range of several questions, in order to prepare these questions to deletion (unfortunately together with the answers). I don't know how to properly name such actions...

Comment: Well, another take on this matter, @Widawensen, is to refrain from answering no-effort PSQ's?

Comment: @Widawensen FWIW I have also noticed a surge in questionable downvotes during the past week or so, quite a few clearly targeted at getting the question itself to be deleted by downvoting *all* answers (which did in fact succeed in some of those cases). I personally find it *highly* inconsiderate that someone would cast a downvote without even a hint to the poster as to why, and ironic that those serial downvoters feel the need to hide such self-righteous crusades behind the anonymity that allows them to game the system. All that said, life is too short to waste on worrying about downvotes ;-)

Comment: @amWhy Answering   the question can be sometimes more important for the answering person than OP as it allows him/her to clarify his/hers knowledge and can play important role in the process of education. Deleting their work is simply destroying this process. We should respect our works mutually.

Comment: @dxiv A single person is always on the lost position against hidden group which has their own aims and coordinates their efforts, even if some motivation of the participants is "good". What was a kind of surprise to me that we are all vulnerable to such actions and sometimes without explanations of other users  we would not even  know what's going on. In fact  the most devastating  group's effect of their actions (probably unforeseen by them) would be the possibility to enforce losing motivation for the active participation in MSE..

Comment: @Widawensen  If you want so badly to answer homework questions, get yourself a text in Algebra-Precal, Calc, Elementary number theory, and write you answers to the exercises (problem statement questions, all of them) on a personal blog you create.

Comment: @amWhy Telling someone to essentially "*go away*" is not terribly constructive. You are entitled to your opinions, of course, but so is everyone else. And if the consensus on PSQs was as strong as you make it sound, then there wouldn't be the *same* 3-4 users responsible for most deletions in the past days.

Comment: @dxiv Then why do you engage in telling me and others to "go away"?   Don't say "I never said that!", Because neither did I ever ask the asker to "go away".  Don't put words in my mouth.  There are far more than 3-4 users who at times delete questions.  I typically try to keep my actions more current, to help keep out incoming crap.  And questions can't get deleted unless they've also been  put on hold, silly dxiv.  You know that.  So it turns out that you're misrepresenting the scenario, as all disgruntled answerers-who-answer-incredibly-poor-questions do. Hint: answer good questions!

Comment: It really is interesting that those who complain about very poor questions being deleted tend only to be the users who chose to answer them.  (oops, you lost rep!)

Comment: The choice is every user's: answer PSQs/do-my-work-for-me-and-now!/follow-my-link-to-figure-out-my-question/no-effort/nonsense, and risk the deletion of the question (and with the deletion of a question, goes also all answers), or answer the many, many questions asked in good faith, with effort from the asker, or a responsive asker who doesn't rudely dump a question, but sticks around a few minutes after posting a question to answer comments, clarify, etc.  No one forces anyone to answer crap.   So don't come whining to meta to berate the users who recognized crap, as crap, and deleted it.

Comment: @amWhy `silly dxiv` If your level of discourse decayed to name-calling now, then bye for good.

Comment: @dxiv "hide such self-righteous crusades behind the anonymity that allows them to game the system" This part of your comment stunned me. Which anonymity is there when the username of every user voting to put on hold a question is shown once the question is put on hold? Likewise for "delete" and for "reopen" instead of "put on hold"? And even for reopened posts, see for example [the first question linked above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2448604): it was reopened by 5 users whose names are in clear ...

Comment: ... on [the revision page](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2448604/revisions), after having been closed by 5 users whose names are also in clear on the same page. So, **what is hidden?** ("To game the system" would also require some serious clarifications but let us stick to the "hidden" thing for now.)

Comment: @Did I didn't know about this activity and probably I would not know if   Mark did not tell me. Note that so far the question has no answer from any  of the PSQ members ( let me use such name as I have somehow to refer to the group as it is acting as the entity). Do you think that at least the answer for the question could be put in the form: " The answer for the question is CRUDE room" ? Nothing more.  It would make known the fact to the other users. BTW the name "CRUDE room" until now was not quoted in meta in this context. Maybe the time has come for official presentation?

Comment: Again, **no "group is acting as the entity"**. That you insist on the notion, despite having been explained its absurdity, is more telling than you know.

Comment: @Did `Which anonymity` The anonymity of the serial downvotes on both questions and all their posted answers, which is a step towards rushing the deletion.

Comment: @Widawensen I sincerely hope that I never become a member of the PSQ group.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг Indeed, it is interesting also that someone could be involved in their actions even without knowing  what's going on. I regarded closing posts as the sum of individual actions of non-coordinated single users, but as we see it can be something more..

Comment: Looks like the PSQ thing is the most vehemently debated topic on meta (see for example https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27918/72031). I think the problem is aggravated because of the downvotes to answers for PSQs. While I am against the PSQs and do engage in their closure/deletion occasionally, I don't downvote mathematically correct answers but then not everyone has similar opinion.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh I would lean towards opinion that all thread is important. What is deleted in fact it is not only homework-question but also sometimes high quality answers which take much more time to work out them than question copied  probably from the book..

Comment: @Widawensen: fully agree. But in such cases where we have reasonably good answers one can try to reopen/undelete them via the R and U letters of CRUDE.

Comment: @Widawensen I think, then, that we must strive to do this : downvote poorly formatted questions, but upvote any excellent answers to these questions. I think the "flow" of downvoting leads to high quality answers to poor questions also getting downvoted. The reason why some others were getting agitated on this thread, is that maybe they feel that good answers should correlate with good questions . So, don't expend effort to please users who don't expend effort to please you. Keep your expectations of questions high, and give it your best effort only if your know it meets that requirement.

Comment: That message in the previous comment  is not directed at anybody in particular, but I believe it is a message that should be taken in by everyone who likes to answer questions on the site.

Comment: Also see continuation of discussion in https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28390/is-crude-healthy